# Psychological variables: Right percentage of subjects to choose when comparing subjects depending on their level on Neuroticism (Eysenck's model)

Tags: t-test, psychometrics, psychology

I am trying to analyze some data regarding the relationship between Neuroticism/Stability, from Eysenck's model of personality, and ease of use (one of the dimensions of the TAM model, by Davis) when applied to the intended use of software methods.

My intention is to check whether there are significant differences in the perceived ease of use reported by the subjects depending on whether Neuroticism is high or low with a t-test. My problem is where to establish the cut-off point for the high and low groups. Somewhere (and that's my problem, I do not remember in which article) I read that some researchers typically used the 27% top values and 27% lower values in order to define such groups (so that middle N values do not cloud such impact) but I am not sure if this is the right decision. The sample size (55) is rather low, and Pearson's correlation coefficient is not able to detect any meaningful relationship (nor was expected).

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: This seems to require expertise in psychology to answer well, but nothing in your title or tags is flagging that to attract attention from experts (not me). 27% seems utterly arbitrary as a cut-off. If you can't give a reference or an argument for that, it's hard to know what to say, except crucially why do you need to group here at all? If you have  measurements on some key variable, use it ungrouped as a predictor, even if there are some gaps in a sample.  Also, $N$ without explanation in  a statistical forum would usually be taken to be sample size, but I guess that you mean Neuroticism!

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! I have edited the question to try to clarify it. The relationship between Neuroticism and Ease of Use is not linear, so Pearson's correlation coefficient does not work. My research question is rather whether people with high levels of Neuroticism find significantly more difficult to learn a new software development method.

Comment: It sounds as if you may  need to to use nonlinear transformations and/or a non-identity link. Your research question sounds malformed to me. If you identify what the relationship is, there may be a threshold although you shouldn't assume there to be one. Why not show your data: you have a small sample, so that's feasible?

Comment: Why not show the data to get better advice? If you think there is a threshold or stepped response, then Pearson correlation and how far the relationship is linear are irrelevant. I'd rather see the data and/or a scatter plot to judge.

Answer (score 0):

Don't dichotomize the variable in the first place. It has many ordered values, so instead of splitting it into two groups and using a $t$-test, test the correlation between it and ease of use. You can use the Kendall correlation rather than the Pearson correlation to avoid issues regarding the nonlinearity of the neuroticism scale.